# URL Encoding issue in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, url-encoding

I am getting url from my server response as:

https://baseURL/The+Man+in+the+High+Castle+Official+Trailer+%E2%80%93+2+th.m3u8

and i am doing encoding as :

```
 videoURL = videoURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

but avplayer not able to play this particular url .
seems like some issue in encoding URL

Comment: Why you are using "stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters" when you already have encoded string. Just use simple String append.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is already percent-encoded.

If you encode it again, the percent parts will be encoded twice, giving an invalid URL.

You can see that by removing the percent encoding from your URL and setting it again:

```
let base = "https://baseURL/The+Man+in+the+High+Castle+Official+Trailer+%E2%80%93+2+th.m3u8"
let decoded = base.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!
print(decoded)
let encoded = decoded.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())!
print(encoded)
```

Comment: PERFECT REASON !! DOUBLE ENCODING WAS THE ISSUE... THANK YOU SO MUCH IT HELPED SOLVE MY YEAR OLD ISSUE, CAN'T THANK ENOUGH.. TAKE A BOW :)

Comment: @DhavalH.Nena Ah! You're welcome. I'm glad it was helpful.